# fade out one image, fade in second

Tags: jquery, css, position

I want one image to slowly fade out, while the second image slowly fades in. Both images should be at the same position ofcourse. How can I achieve this without setting their styles to position: absolute?

Comment: Have you considered the jQuery Cycle plugin?  The lite version supports fade only so if that's the only effect you need go with that.

Comment: Why the no absolute positioning? Can you not just wrap them in a relatively positioned div?

Answer (score 2):

try something like...

```
$('imageOneSelector').fadeOut(1000, function(){
   $(this).replaceWith(new image html);
   $('imageOneSelector').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

**UPDATE:**

heres a jsfiddle test without the images but should be the same concept...

http://jsfiddle.net/qWngq/1/

Comment: Wouldn't this fade one image out completely then fade the next in? (ie not fading out at the same time as the other fades in)

Comment: @what ... yes thats true. I guess that may not be the exact behavior the op is looking for though...

Comment: some variation of this may give the results your looking for though